# ImportError: No module named rospkg (python3) <SOLVED>

Tags: ros, rospkg, python3

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I am using ROS Indigo in Raspbian Jessie on Raspberry pi 3, I am trying of read a compass (HC5883L) using library for read ports i2c (i2clibraries and quick2wire-python-api) but, when I run my file it given me this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/ros_catkin_ws/src/ceres_pkg/src/Brujula.py", line 5, in <module>
    import roslib; roslib.load_manifest('ceres_pkg')
  File "/home/pi/ros_catkin_ws/devel/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslib/__init__.py", line 35, in <module>
    exec(__fh.read())
  File "<string>", line 50, in <module>
  File "/home/pi/ros_catkin_ws/src/ros/roslib/src/roslib/launcher.py", line 42, in <module>
    import rospkg
ImportError: No module named 'rospkg'
```

this is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3 #I use python3 because quick2wire only run with this.
import sys
sys.path.append("/home/pi/ros_catkin_ws/src/ceres_pkg/src/quick2wire-python-api")
import time
import roslib; roslib.load_manifest('ceres_pkg')
import rospy
import math
from geometry_msgs.msg import Point
from i2clibraries import i2c_hmc5883l

class Brujula(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.pub_ = rospy.Publisher("/Brujula", Point, queue_size = 1)
        return
    def start(self):
        loop_rate = rospy.Rate(1)
        while not rospy.is_shutdown():
            hmc5883l = i2c_hmc5883l.i2c_hmc5883l(1)
            hmc5883l.setDeclination(9,54)
            hmc = float(hmc5883l.getHeadingString())
            pos_msg = Point(hmc)
            self.pub_.publish(pos_msg);
            loop_rate.sleep()
        return

if __name__ == '__main__':
    rospy.init_node('Brujula_py', log_level=rospy.INFO)
    rospy.loginfo("%s: starting Brujulagps node", rospy.get_name())
    brujula = Brujula()
    brujula.start()
```

My first step was read the compas, like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys
import time
sys.path.append("/home/pi/ros_catkin_ws/src/ceres_pkg/src/quick2wire-python-api")
from i2clibraries import i2c_hmc5883l
while True:
    hmc5883l = i2c_hmc5883l.i2c_hmc5883l(1)
    hmc5883l.setDeclination(9,54)
    hmc = float(hmc5883l.getHeadingString())
    print(hmc)
    time.sleep(1)
```

But, when I convert to ROS code, this its broken.

Thanks for your time, and I hope that someone can help me.

---

Edit: I can solve, I install `python3-rospkg`:

```
sudo apt-get install python3-rospkg
```

But now, I have a new mistake:

```
ImportError: No module named 'catkin_pkg'
```

I tried to install

```
sudo apt-get install python3-catkin_pkg
```

But don't find any.

Any suggestions?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/245967/importerror:-no-module-named-rospkg-(python3)-%3Csolved%3E/) by [DannyMB](https://answers.ros.org/users/28114/dannymb/) on ROS Answers with karma: 77 on 2016-10-19

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) on 2016-10-19**:
have you sourced the ROS workspace? I.e., does `echo $ROS_PACKAGE_PATH` in the terminal you are trying to run this return anything? If yes, please edit your question with this output.

Also, I'm not quite sure how safe ROS is currently for python3.

**Comment by [DannyMB](https://answers.ros.org/users/28114/dannymb/) on 2016-10-19**:
Yes, I have my worksapace, and all the proyect there is, for to run the file I use:

pi@raspberry: ~/ros_catkin_ws/src/ceres_pkg/src $ rosrun ceres_pkg Brujula.py

**Comment by [systembulangen](https://answers.ros.org/users/100053/systembulangen/) on 2022-03-22**:
sudo apt install python-is-python3

**Comment by [systembulangen](https://answers.ros.org/users/100053/systembulangen/) on 2022-03-22**:
This is an issue because Ubuntu 20.04 has dropped python and python2, and now using python 3. Install the following lib to run ROS on Ubuntu 20.04: sudo apt install python-is-python3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

`sudo apt-get install python3-catkin-pkg`

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2016-10-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [DannyMB](https://answers.ros.org/users/28114/dannymb/) on 2016-10-19**:
Thanks @ahendrix ! that was the solution!

**Comment by [csherstan](https://answers.ros.org/users/9751/csherstan/) on 2017-01-23**:
I'm running indigo on Ubuntu 14.04. Running this command causes apt to uninstall ROS for me.

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2017-01-27**:
I'd guess your problem is that python3-catkin-pkg *conflicts* with python-catkin-pkg, and much of ROS depends on that (python 2) version. You probably have to build ROS in a virtualenv from source using python3, instead. Good luck with that!

**Comment by [Ari.Schneider](https://answers.ros.org/users/28913/ari.schneider/) on 2017-06-18**:
I had the same problem as you, csherstan. I solved this problem by installing the catkin_pkgs with the command:

```
sudo apt-get install python-catkin-pkg
```

And then I installed the python3-catkin-pkg-modules, with the command

```
sudo apt-get install python3-catkin-pkg-modules
```

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is what worked for me:

```
sudo apt-get install python3-catkin-pkg-modules
sudo apt-get install python3-rospkg-modules
```

I am using ROS Kinetic on Ubuntu 16.04 in a Jetson TX2.

---

Originally posted by [gustavo.velascoh](https://answers.ros.org/users/2667/gustavo.velascoh/) with karma: 756 on 2018-07-23

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 11

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [billtheplatypus](https://answers.ros.org/users/35184/billtheplatypus/) on 2018-07-26**:
I had to do this for Melodic on 18.04

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2018-07-26**:
In the future upgrading the Debian package of any of the ROS Python packages (`catkin_pkg`, `rospkg`, `rosdistro`, `ros_buildfarm`) will ensure that the `-modules` Debian package is updated too: see https://github.com/ros-infrastructure/rosdistro/pull/122

**Comment by [ticotico](https://answers.ros.org/users/58821/ticotico/) on 2021-11-17**:
this should be the accepted answer